# simple_salesforce.exceptions.SalesforceAuthenticationFailed: INVALID_LOGIN: Invalid username, password, security token; or user locked out

Tags: airflow, salesforce-lightning

from simple_salesforce import Salesforce
import pandas as pd

```
sf = Salesforce(
username='test@example.com', 
password='password', 
security_token='the_provided_access_token')
```

I am not getting any errors while executing the code above, but getting this error below.
I can see the login attempt with the SOAP Partner device with "Logged Out" STATUS from Account Activity as well.

airflow code

```
salesforce_hook = SalesforceHook(salesforce_conn_id=self.salesforce_conn_id)
salesforce_fields = salesforce_hook.get_available_fields(self.object)
```

error

/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/simple_salesforce/login.py line 237, in soap_login

```
raise SalesforceAuthenticationFailed(except_code, except_msg)
simple_salesforce.exceptions.SalesforceAuthenticationFailed: 
INVALID_LOGIN: Invalid username, password, security token; or user locked out.
```

I'm not sure if the issue is due to IP whitelisting, but are there any other factors that I should investigate?